# Select only one entry per ID

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working with a system that perodically updates itself, within this system I try to select the highest 500 and list them. However, the problem is that I sort it by a varchar that contains a date in the format of 2013-07-08, this is a relic and for the time being I am annoyingly not allowed to change this to a proper date for easy sorting.

My question is, how can I select only 1 of the following 3 pretended results?

id| value | ownerid | date

```
1| 21300 | 1       | 2013-07-08
2| 21300 | 1       | 2013-07-08
3| 21300 | 1       | 2013-07-08
```

What I need done is to select one entry from each ownerid, which is the one with the highest value (if it's all the same it doesn't really matter which entry, just that it's only one!)

This is using a mysql database with PDO as the database layer.

Thankful for any and all help!

Comment: in pure SQL, `GROUP BY 'date'` springs to mind

Comment: You have to decide, which of this row you need? Anyway, you could add GROUP BY statement to your query

Comment: Well, I am thinking about sorting it somehow to only select the latest ID, so that the most recent information is always displayed

Comment: "it doesn't really matter which" - this kind of statement is sometimes symptomatic of poor design. Just sayin'

Answer (score 0):

Use a sub-query with a `GROUP BY` to get a particular id for each day (max or min for example) then `JOIN` that against the table to get the rest of the details:

```
SELECT a.id, a.value, a.ownerid, a.date
FROM SomeTable a
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT date, MAX(id) AS MaxId
    FROM SomeTable
    GROUP BY date
) b
ON a.date = b.date
AND a.id = b.MaxId
```

Modified version to get the highest value row for each day. As value isn't unique I have done a further sub select to get the highest id for that highest value. Without this you could get multiple rows returned for a day. If there is zero chance of the other values every being different you could use DISTINCT to remove the multiples, but normally not possible to be certain of that.

```
SELECT a.id, a.`value`, a.ownerid, a.`date`
FROM SomeTable a
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT `date`, MAX(`value`) AS MaxVal
    FROM SomeTable
    GROUP BY `date`
) b
ON a.`date` = b.`date`
AND a.`value` = b.MaxVal
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT `date`, `value`, MAX(id) AS MaxId
    FROM SomeTable
    GROUP BY `date`, `value`
) c
ON b.`date` = c.`date`
AND b.MaxVal = c.`value`
AND a.id = c.MaxId
```

Comment: I realised by looking at your code that I have not been really clear. Updating main post for clarity.

Comment: I see this query does almost what it's supposed to do, however it does select just one entry per day. However, my goal is to select the last 500 entries posted sorted by value desc. I'm not sure if I am capable of expressing the issue further. I'm playing around with your code however to learn it better, and with some experience I might perhaps work it out. Thanks for the help so far however!

Comment: I can try to come up with something. How do you decide the last 500 items?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM [table] 
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(yourdatefield, '%m/%d/%Y') DESC 
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: This is not going to work sadly, it will still return multiple entries per ownerid & date. This is a "todays top 500" style list I'm working with.